# How to configure python cffi library to use mingw?

Tags: python, mingw, python-cffi

Attempting to call cffi.FFI.verify() on windows will produce this error:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I want to use mingw to compile instead of msvc. I tried to make distutils use mingw by creating c:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg  with

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

but this doesn't seem to affect cffi, I still get vcvarsall.bat missing error.

So how can I make cffi use gcc/mingw (or in general other C compiler)?

Comment: What does return `gcc --version` in a Command Prompt ? Is the path to `MinGW/bin` correctly set in your `PATH` env. var. ?

Comment: Yes they are. I can invoke gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 from the same cmd prompt I want to run the python script. Windows path contains MinGW/bin dir

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall cffi, now that distutils is properly configured. 
For example using `easy_install`

```
easy_install cffi
```

Or even rebuild & install it from source using MinGW that way :

```
cd cffi-src-dir
python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32 install
cd ..
```

This will make sure that cffi is correctly setup for use with MinGW... I guess...

Comment: well, using pip or easy_install first fails with a distutils error complaining about a bad "-mno-cygwin" argument. After I remove said compiler argument from distutils/cygwincompiler.py (as per this problem http://bugs.python.org/issue12641), compilation starts but down in other gcc errors. I'll give up for the moment.

Comment: Compiling from sources does not help, because setup.py uses distutils, hence you run into exactly the same issues as with pip or easy_install. BTW, initially I installed cffi by using the unofficial binaries from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. It works if you only use ABI, but when trying to use the API (and hence compile C) it fails as described in my original question